# how can I add more sprites on SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to make interface of a game, and I've got some image files(all of them are PNG).
These are image files : Tank, map, statusbar, barguage

and here's my code

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cassert>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML works!");
    sf::Texture tex;
    sf::Sprite map;
    sf::Sprite tank;
    enter code here

    assert(tex.loadFromFile("map_skybridge.png"));

    map.setTexture(tex);
    tank.setTexture(tex);

    sf::Event event;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(map);

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder how could I add more sprites.. I'd like to put them on map image.

Comment: Important note: `assert()` should only ever include non-mandatory checks. It's very likely the whole call/line will be removed for release builds, screwing up your program in some way. So rather than doing this the way you did, you should store the return value and use that in the `assert()` call. Although you should probably add proper error handling instead.

Answer (score 1):

You'd just create more texture objects – one `sf::Texture` per image and load the files the same way you did so far:

```
sf::Texture texMap;
sf::Texture texTank;

texMap.loadFromFile("map.png");
texTank.loadFromFile("tank.png");
```

As for drawing, there are multiple approaches. You could create only one sprite per type of thing to draw or you could create one sprite per actual game object (e.g. 2 tanks using the same sprite or two separate sprites):

```
sf::Sprite sprMap;
sf::Sprite sprTank;

sprMap.setTexture(texMap);
sprTank.setTexture(texTank);
```

Then just draw your sprites as usual:

```
window.draw(sprMap);
window.draw(sprTank);
```

Of course you could move the sprites using `sf::Sprite::setPosition()` etc.